# Rails 3.2.11 does a get request when its actually a delete request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey guys i dunno how to put this i have done a bit ror..I kinda changed all my work to my new lap and i have win 7 and i am usin ror 3.2.11 for most of my projects...The problem is that when i do

```
<%= link_to("Delete", user, :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure that you want to delete this user") %>
```

it renders as

```
<a href="/users/1" data-confirm="Are you sure that you want to delete this user" data-method="destroy" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>
```

but when i click this link it actually does a get request here are the server logs

```
Started GET "/users/3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-20 06:21:40 +0530
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "3"]]
  Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (2.0ms)
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_body.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 19ms (Views: 19.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: What do your routes look like for `User`?

Comment: This won't solve your problem, however Rails 3.2.11 is vulnerable to a remote code execution vulnerability. You should upgrade to 3.2.12 ASAP. More information: bit.ly/UdLiVr

Comment: Are you sure you are includong the ujs library ? `//= require jquery_ujs` More info over here : https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs

Comment: I just figured out that for **deletion to work in rails 3.0** and up the application.html.erb must have `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` this line in the head part. And for me this raised an exception for me I dont remember the exception exactly but it was due to the javascript include tag so what you gotta do for that is just delete a commented out line from the app/assets/javascripts/application.js that says `= require_tree` hope this helps someone out there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 things are require for this to work (your code is correct)

Gemfile must contain

```
group :assets do
  gem 'jquery-rails'
end
```

views/layouts/application.html.(erb or haml) must contain in the header tag

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

assets/javascripts/application.js must contain

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```